# Can I download the wallet and blockchain to an external disk?

Tags: blockchain, mist, storage

I am running on a macbook air and suffering from incredibly small storage space. Is it possible for me to download the wallet + sync the blockchain and securely store my tokens on the external disk?

Other answeres I have found have suggested transferring the files from local to external, but I am unable to save it locally to begin with

What are my options?

Looking forward to getting stuck into solidity and writing some smart contracts :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can download the --datadir folder you had given when you start the ethereum node.

So all the keystore files will be with you.

Then move to another machine, start the ethereum node with datadir which you copied now.

Make sure you copy the ~./ethash folder too, and replace in the new machine ~./ethash folder.

If you want to work with smart contracts try with metamask plugin.

Comment: I just downloaded the Mist wallet, moved it to my external disk and launched it but I don't see any --datadir or ~./ethash dir. Hidden files are visible

Comment: By --datadir they mean the `~/Library/Ethereum` on macs